# Passing function arguments by position: Do explicit values get used before pipeline input?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-4.0

I'm experimenting with creating a function that can take multiple arguments by position, including pipeline input.

Here's a simple test function:

```
function TestMultiplePositionalParameters
{
    param
    (  
        [Parameter(
            Position=0, 
            Mandatory=$true)
        ]
        [String]$FirstParam,

        [Parameter(
            Position=1, 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            ValueFromPipeline=$true)
        ]
        [String]$SecondParam
    ) 

    begin
    {
        Write-Host '================================='
    }

    process
    {
        Write-Host '$FirstParam:' $FirstParam
        Write-Host '$SecondParam:' $SecondParam
        Write-Host ''        
    }
}
```

When I call it, it works fine:

```
"Input1","Input2" | TestMultiplePositionalParameters 'ExplicitArgument'
```

Which results in:

```
=================================
$FirstParam: ExplicitArgument
$SecondParam: Input1

$FirstParam: ExplicitArgument
$SecondParam: Input2
```

However, if I change the parameter which takes the value from the pipeline:

```
function TestMultiplePositionalParameters
{
    param
    (  
        [Parameter(
            Position=0, 
            Mandatory=$true, 
            ValueFromPipeline=$true)
        ]
        [String]$FirstParam,

        [Parameter(
            Position=1, 
            Mandatory=$true)
        ]
        [String]$SecondParam
    ) 

    # etc...

}
```

And again call it:

```
"Input1","Input2" | TestMultiplePositionalParameters 'ExplicitArgument'
```

This time I get an error:

```
TestMultiplePositionalParameters : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters 
for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input 
and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\...\DEMO_Function_Pipeline_MultiPositionalParams.ps1:77 char:21
+ "Input1","Input2" | TestMultiplePositionalParameters 'ExplicitArgument'
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Input1:String) 
   [TestMultiplePositionalParameters ], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,TestMultiplePositionalParameters
```

My question is:  Why does the second version of the function pass the explicit argument 'ExplicitArgument' to the first parameter?  I would have thought that given only the first parameter can accept pipeline input the function should have passed the pipeline input to the first parameter and the explicit argument to the second parameter.

Comment: Doing what you expected would require the command to start, check for input and then bind arguments (I think). That seems an odd way to have something function.

Comment: Is that not what actually happens when a function takes piped input?  In my question I left out the fact that I got two errors, one for each value passed through the pipeline (`"Input1"` and `"Input2"`).  It looks to me like the function runs the begin block, then goes back and reads the first value from the pipeline and attempts to bind it to a parameter and process it (if it doesn't throw an error, as in the second example above), then it reads the second value from the pipeline and binds and processes it.

Comment: Yes, it processes pipeline input *after* binding the command line arguments (and possibly running begin). Your suggested behavior is *exactly* the opposite of that. It would require assigning pipeline input (before begin and before command line argument assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the second version of the function pass the explicit argument
>   'ExplicitArgument' to the first parameter?

Because `$FirstParam` is marked as being at position '0' and the first parameter passed to the cmdlet is 'ExplicitArgument'. Essentially, the binding of 'ExplicitArgument' to `$FirstParam` has already happened by the time PowerShell is looking for a parameter that will accept pipeline input.

To get your expected behaviour, you would have to execute the following:

```
"Input1","Input2" | TestMultiplePositionalParameters -SecondParam 'ExplicitArgument'
```

The reason for this is that you can have more than one parameter that accepts its value from the pipeline. If you had the following, what would you expect to happen in your second example?

```
param
(  
    [Parameter(
        Position=0, 
        Mandatory=$true, 
        ValueFromPipeline=$true)
    ]
    [String]$FirstParam,

    [Parameter(
        Position=1, 
        Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true)
    ]
    [String]$SecondParam
)
```

There has to be a precedence and it is that named and positional arguments have higher priority than the pipeline arguments.

Comment: A reference to documentation indicating this binding order would be a good addition (if there is one).

Comment: @EtanReisner I looked at `about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` and it does not explicitly say that `Position` has precedence over `ValueFromPipeline`. Therefore, we have to deduce it from experience.

Comment: Indeed. I also didn't see anything in there (or the few other places I looked) that indicated this. It would be nice if one existed though (even if I think this is the natural order and the suggested alternative would **greatly** surprise me).

Comment: @Swoogan: Very clear answer, thank you.  I also couldn't find any documentation about the binding order of function parameters.